# Higher Order Component state is updating correctly but wrapped component receiving props not re-rendering on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I have this HOC which is passing dailyTime into a wrapped component thats sole function is to display the time spent. It's receiving it's props fine on initial render/page load. A second component which receives the updateTime prop and calls getDailyStats upon exercise completion is being called correctly and the getDailyStats is running and the state is being updated in the HOC (the console.log in the render is always updating) however my wrapped component which is receiving that update is rerendering upon state change. I'm wondering if it doesn't have something to do with recompose? Regardless, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const withDailyStats = WrappedComponent => {

  class withDailyStats extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
      };
    }


  getDailyStats = async () => {
    const authUser = this.props.authUser.uid
    let userSets = await this.props.firebase.sets()
      .where('userId', '==', authUser)
      .get()

    let data = userSets.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    let now = moment()
    let pastDay =  moment().startOf('day')
    let pastWeek =  moment().startOf('week')

    let todaySets =  data.filter(set => {
      const setTime = moment((set.createdAt.toDate()))
      return setTime >= pastDay
    })

    let todaysTime = todaySets.reduce((a, b) => a + (parseFloat(b['time']) || 0), 0)
    todaysTime = this.msToTime(todaysTime);

    this.setState({
      dailyTime: todaysTime, 
      todaySets
    })
  }


   msToTime = (s) => {
    // Pad to 2 or 3 digits, default is 2
    function pad(n, z) {
      z = z || 2;
      return ('00' + n).slice(-z);
   }

    var ms = s % 1000;
    s = (s - ms) / 1000;
    var secs = s % 60;
    s = (s - secs) / 60;
    var mins = s % 60;
    var hrs = (s - mins) / 60;

    return pad(hrs) + ':' + pad(mins) + ':' + pad(secs) 
  }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.getDailyStats()
    }


    render() {
      console.log('HOC STATE', this.state.dailyTime)
      return <WrappedComponent dailyTime={this.state.dailyTime} {...this.props} updateTime=. 
              {this.getDailyStats} />;
    }
  };

return compose(
  withFirebase, 
  withAuthentication,
  )(withDailyStats);
}

export default withDailyStats;
```

Here is the wrapped component that is not updating. It used to be functional but i changed it to a class component just as a test.

```
class DailyStatModule extends React.Component { 
  state = {}

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('daily mount', this.props.dailyTime)
  }


  render() {
    console.log('DSM', this.props)
    return (
      <DailyWrapper >
        <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClock} sz="lg" />
          <div>{this.props.dailyTime}</div>
        </div>
      </DailyWrapper>
    );
  }
}




export default withDailyStats(DailyStatModule)
```

Comment: Is there any reason of giving HOC and component same `withDailyStats` name? I am just wondering if compose function is using the HOC instead of component. Can u please try renaming one of those  ?

Comment: Just tried renaming out wrapper wtihDailyStatsWrapper and importing that... did not work. Thought it might have worked, seemed like a good idea.... @VishalSharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `withDailyStats` hoc is being used by 2 components. `getDailyStats` is executed by say `Component1` which updates the withDailyStats's state. This update will not be propagated to `DailyStatModule` component. Sorry.

React, by design, is one way data flow. In your case, you can use, [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) or

Also, take a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54830400/sharing-content-between-adjacent-components-hoc)

Comment: Yeah i was trying to avoid using redux. Although, that does all make sense. Will just add a context provider/consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I assuming the wrapped component only rendered once initially as componentDidMount was used?

I think you might want to try componentDidUpdate on the wrapped component to compare props for subsequent updates.

Details here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate